# How can I unmute me automaticaly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, microsoft-teams

my friends always are muting me and i want to auto unmute. I tried this:

```js
if (document.getElementById("ui-toolbar__item bh dm mp mq mr ms ap aq ar as cg ch ci cj ck mt dk bx cq bz cr b dq eb dz mu dx dy ed ee ef eg eh ei ej ek el em en ls lt lu lv es et eu ev ew ex ey ez fb fc fd fe ff fg fh fi fj lw lx ly lz fo fp fq fr fs ft fu fv fw fx mv mw mx my mz na nb")) {
document.getElementById("ui-toolbar__item bh dm mp mq mr ms ap aq ar as cg ch ci cj ck mt dk bx cq bz cr b dq eb dz mu dx dy ed ee ef eg eh ei ej ek el em en ls lt lu lv es et eu ev ew ex ey ez fb fc fd fe ff fg fh fi fj lw lx ly lz fo fp fq fr fs ft fu fv fw fx mv mw mx my mz na nb").click()
}
```

I know it isnt a loop yet but it wont click the unmute mic button. Can someone tell me whats wrong? Im very new to js. Im not getting any errors or something but it wont unmute. Its in teams.

Comment: What won't unmute? What's "it" ? Also an ID can't have spaces in it

Comment: The unmute button in teams, Oh ok thanks maybe thats why it isnt working

Answer (score 1):

In Microsoft Teams latest version using web browser, you only have to do this :

```
$("#microphone-button").click()
```

However, if you want a loop, you'll have to trigger the click only if the microphone is currently muted, otherwise you'll mute yourself.

Here the full code including check for microphone muted and loop :

```
setInterval(function(){
    if($("#microphone-button > ng-include > svg").hasClass("icons-call-microphone-off-filled")){
        $("#microphone-button").click();
    }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thank you but im using the program. My friend wrote an injector and now its working